# sql query not inserting data into database table from array

Tags: php, sql

The code bellow is supposed to insert data(firstname,fathername,lastname,medicalinsurance) from personprofile table into organandtissuedonationcommittee table along with "organ donated" if prioritylvl==1 and same data as in the () along with "pending" when  prioritylvl==2/3
Please help me I can't find out what I did wrong. Here is the code

```
    // check the prioritylvl if 1 insert organstatus as transplant completed if 2 or 3 then organstatus as pending
$sqlpersonprofile= "SELECT firstname,fathername,lastname,medicalinsurance,prioritylvl,admissionreason FROM personprofile";
$patients=  mysqli_query($link,$sqlpersonprofile);
$processpriority= mysqli_fetch_assoc($patients);
if($processpriority['prioritylvl'] == 1 && $processpriority['admissionreason'] == 5 ){
//dont forget to add the organ status
    $sqlcommittee= 'INSERT INTO organandtissuedonationcommittee(firstname,fathername,lastname,insurance,organstatus)  
    VALUES("$processpriority['firstname']","$processpriority['fathername']","$processpriority['lastname']","$processpriority['medicalinsurance']","Organ donated")';
    $committee = mysqli_query($link, $sqlcommittee);

        if(!$committee){
                echo 'Not inserted';
            }
}
if($processpriority['prioritylvl'] == 2 || $processpriority['prioritylvl'] == 3 && $processpriority['admissionreason'] == 5 ){
//dont forget to add the organ status
    $sqlcommittee= 'INSERT INTO organandtissuedonationcommittee(firstname,fathername,lastname,insurance,organstatus)  
    VALUES("$processpriority['firstname']","$processpriority['fathername']","$processpriority['lastname']","$processpriority['medicalinsurance']","Pending")';
    $committee = mysqli_query($link, $sqlcommittee);

        if(!$committee){
                echo 'Not inserted';
            }
}
```

Comment: Well if you are getting the `not inserted` message did you check to see what `mysqli_error()` gives and see if there is some sql error message? Or have you checked the server error logs for syntax error messages?

Comment: It gives me this error -  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'firstname' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\bloodonation\bloodonation.php on line 138

Comment: Take a look at your string literal for the sql queries, you have single quotes inside your string but are using single quotes as the string delimiter.

Comment: I know I tried using single quotes inside [] but they don't seem to work